# If statement has me stumped

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post ever and I am extremely new to vba so please be gentle.
I have created a user form that has Territory (TextBox5), Weight (TextBox1), City (TextBox3) and Cost (TextBox4). This is a form to calculate the cost of shipping with a certain trucking company. There are rates that are associated with the weight AND THE City. If the city is Within the Territory there is a rate per 100lbs up to a max of 9000lbs. However, if the rate is Outside Of Territory then there is a higher rate per 100lbs up to a max of 9000lbs.
Within Territory has a minimum of $15.00 and Outside of Territory has a minimum of $20.00.
     This is just on of the ways i have tried....

```
 Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
     Dim A As Single
     A = Val(TextBox1.Text)
     If (TextBox5.Text = "Within Territory" And TextBox1.Text <= 233) Then
         TextBox4.Text = TextBox1.Text * 6.5 / 100 * 1.3
         If (TextBox5.Text = "Out of Territory" And TextBox1.Text <= 200) Then
             TextBox4.Text = TextBox1.Text * 10 / 100 * 1.3
         End If
    End If       
End Sub
```

I wanted to run through and put all of the rates in at the different weights and all but i couldn't even get this part to work. The division of 100 is for the per 100lbs. and the 1.3 is the 30% fuel surcharge.

rates for within territory are as follows... Minimum 15.00....6.50 per 100 up to 999lbs...6.00 from 1000 up to 1999 lbs....from 2000 up to a maximum of 9000 lbs. is 5.50

for outside of territory rates are: min of 20.00...the same in lbs. frequency is 10.00, 9.25, 8.00.

any help or suggestions in the right direction will be GREATLY appreciated!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a bit more structured approach will help.

- Separate your data from your logic (makes it easier to maintain)
- Use something like `If` weight in first band `Then` calculate rate `Else` consider next band
- I don't think you want to do this on `TextBox4` change (cost).  Probably on any other textbox change.

Try this (call from Territory or Weight textbox change events)

```
Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
    Dim weight As Single
    Dim cost As Single

    Dim rates(1 To 3) As Single
    Dim bands(1 To 3) As Single
    Dim min As Single
    Dim surcharge As Single

    weight = Val(TextBox1.Text)

    If weight <= 0# Then
        ' deal with invalid weight
        TextBox4.Text = "Invalid Weight"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TextBox5.Text = "Within Territory" Then
        rates(1) = 6.5
        rates(2) = 6#
        rates(3) = 5.5
        min = 15#
    ElseIf TextBox5.Text = "Out of Territory" Then
        rates(1) = 10#
        rates(2) = 9.25
        rates(3) = 8#
        min = 20#
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    bands(1) = 1000#
    bands(2) = 2000#
    bands(3) = 9000#
    surcharge = 1.3
    If weight > bands(3) Then
        TextBox4.Text = "Weight too big"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If weight < bands(1) Then
        cost = weight * rates(1) / 100#
    Else
        cost = bands(1) * rates(1) / 100#
        If weight < bands(2) Then
            cost = cost + (weight - bands(1)) * rates(2) / 100#
        Else
            cost = cost + (bands(2) - bands(1)) * rates(2) / 100#
            If weight <= bands(3) Then
                cost = cost + (weight - bands(2)) * rates(3) / 100#
            End If
        End If
    End If
    cost = cost * surcharge
    If cost < min Then cost = min

    TextBox4.Text = Format(cost, "#,##0.00")
End Sub
```

Comment: after reading this it makes perfect since, however, textbox4 is still not populating with the result. the cursor moves there but it only blinks with no result.

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug that?  Eg what's the value of `cost` at the end of the sub?

Comment: I don't know what to do to debug. i don't mind the challenge of trying to figure it out so i can learn but i don't even know where to start with your question. I know what value i am looking for but don't know how to make it happen. Im sorry...i am very new.

Comment: Chris, does it matter that Textbox5 is populated from a vlookup?

Comment: No, so long as it takes one of the two values you are testing for.

Comment: Nothing in the code posted should cause `TextBox4` to receive the focus ("the cursor moves there but it only blinks with no result"). Remember that you cannot put this code in the `TextBox4_Change` event because you are changing the value of `TextBox4` and will continually re-trigger the same event. Make sure to put the code in `TextBox1_Change` or `TextBox5_Change`

Comment: is there a way for me to attach my excel workbook so that it can be seen and may make it easier to answer?

Comment: Upload it somewhere (e.g. [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [WeTransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/), [HighTail](https://www.hightail.com/)) and then add the link to your post via an edit. Obviously remove any details you don't want to be made public from the workbook first

Comment: @barrowc.... I am using the code that chris neilsen first sent to me the other day. I took your advice and re-titled it as Private Sub TextBox1_Change()...My userform is simple with 4 text Boxes...at the top is Territory, below that is Weight, below that is City, below that is Cost of Shipment. When I type in the weight and city then TextBox5 (Territory) populates fine but the calculations aren't being done to properly populate TextBox4 (Cost). Weight is Textbox1 and City is Textbox3. There is not a textbox2. I am just so new!! I swear I am trying.

Comment: @barrowc....i don't know if it matters but this is the code i have to populate territory(TextBox5) based on City(TextBox3)value.     Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()
TextBox5.Text = Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox3.Text, Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
End Sub

Comment: From the code in the question the value for `TextBox4` depends on the values from `TextBox5` and `TextBox1`. Presuming that you intend for the user to input the weight `TextBox1` and city `TextBox3` (which will then cause `TextBox5` to populate), for now you need to put the code for populating the cost `TextBox4` into the `TextBox5_Change` event. Eventually you'll need some error-checking (e.g. have both the weight and city been input?) but this should get something working

Answer (score 0):

If this language is a strong-typed language like java, you would need to explicitly change the text to integers to be able to calculate the prices. It also appears that your scale is a sliding scale. If you do not want the numbers to decrease, you would have to add the initial amount ($15 for within territory, $20 for outside territory) to the values that you get. In that case, you could use an if-else statement as follows (this is pseudo-code, not actual vba text): If (Text Box 5 = "Within territory") then str2num (Text Box 4)+= 15. Then you would do the other multiplications and additions as needed inside the loop. else, str2num (Text Box 4) += 20 and do your other calculations from there. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the main pieces of you problem, here is what I would use as a basis to determine the costs. 
See the steps that I have entered below:

Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
    Dim AX As Single
    AX = Val(textBox1.Text)
    If (TextBox5.Text = "Within Territory") Then
        Select Case Val(textBox1.Text)
        Case 100 To 999
            Val(TextBox4.Text) = AX * 6.5 / 100 * 1.3
        Case 1000 To 1999
            Val(TextBox4.Text) = AX * 6# / 100 * 1.3
        Case 2000 To 9000
            Val(TextBox4.Text) = AX * 5.5 / 100 * 1.3
        Case Else
        End Select

```
ElseIf (TextBox5.Text = "Out of Territory") Then
    Select Case Val(textBox1.Text)
    Case 100 To 999
        Val(TextBox4.Text) = AX * 10 / 100 * 1.3
    Case 1000 To 1999
        Val(TextBox4.Text) = AX * 9.5 / 100 * 1.3
    Case 2000 To 9000
        Val(TextBox4.Text) = AX * 8 / 100 * 1.3
    Case Else
    End Select
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: This does not apply the incremental rates as defined in the OP (_6.00 from 1000 up to 1999 lbs_  etc)

Comment: thanks...it looks like you have everything covered... i wouldn't know though because i am so new at this, but it still doesn't populate Textbox4.